# ListView adapter working rows created but are blank

Tags: android, listview, android-6.0-marshmallow

Have spent time reading the posts and did not find anything relevant to the issue experiencing.

Have an android Marshmallow based application that launches an activity which has a layout containing a listview.  Have written a custom adapter which does have it's getView method called and have confirmed that the data is present.  The getView from the adapter is:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,IncidentData>> localList;
            mLayoutInflator = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_base_incident, parent,false);
            }
            mDateTimeText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_text);
            mAddressText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.address_text);
            mDistanceToText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance_to_text);
            mShortDescText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_desc_text);
            mGangRelatedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gang_related_text);
            //pop data

            HashMap<String,IncidentData>incident2 = mID.get(position);
            IncidentData id = incident2.get(incident2.keySet().iterator().next());

            mDateTimeText.setText(id.getDateTime());
            mAddressText.setText(id.getAddress());
            mDistanceToText.setText(String.valueOf(id.getDistance()));
            mShortDescText.setText(id.getShortDesc());
            mGangRelatedText.setText(id.getGangRelated());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SHORT DESC - "+ id.getShortDesc());
            return convertView;
}
```

Log message shows the getView processing each entry in the hashmap correctly.  The issue is that the data is not appearing in the listview however, the listview does display the correct number of blank entries for the amount of data.
Screen layout is as follows:
incident_layout_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/incident_list_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout for the listview contents is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:columnCount="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_time_text"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:text="08201624@2350"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_text"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:text="SAN FERNANDO BLVD AND ALAMEDA AVE"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance_to_text"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/short_desc_text"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:text="Murder"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gang_related_text"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            tools:text="gang related"/>
 </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

The application does launch an intent to handle the display containing the listView.  The intent calls setContentView, gets the data, instantiates the custom adapter and calls setAdapter on it.

Ideas appreciated

Comment: In your TextViews why is it "tools:text"? Shouldn't it be "android:text"?

Comment: No, this line supports tools.text -  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: If I am not mistaken the tools attributes are not applicable at runtime: http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue for no data being displayed.  The background and the text color default to white.  So, while the data was there, yoiu couldn't see it.